# Design pattern - two different return types

Tags: python, design-patterns

My lecturer asked us to write some code in Python. The idea is - we provide number in text form to our class and it returns a number in integer or float type.

Examples:

Input: "two hundred and one"

Output: 201 (integer)

Input: "two point six"

Output: 2.6 (float)

He also asked us to use "suitable design pattern". I know how to write an algorithm, but i have no idea which design pattern i should use, so i can manage multiple return types. I might sound ignorant and my explanation is pretty vague, but you must know we didn't have any kind of introduction to this subject and we are pretty much on our own.

Edit - what i have so far:

```
class NumberInterpreter(object):
   #number_in_string is a number in text form like 'two hundred'
   def __init__(self, number_in_string):
       #contains word lists
       .
       .
       .

   def return_int_number(self):
       #used if number is an integer
       #returns number as integer
       .
       .
       .
       return integer_number

   def return_float_number(self):
       #not implemented
       .
       .
       .
       return float_number
```

Unfortunately i don't have an access to my whole code right now, but i will be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: can you provide us with what you got so far in terms of python

Comment: @Seekheart i edited my original post. Unfortunately i don't have acess to my original code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like either [Catalog](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/catalog.py) or [Strategy](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/strategy.py).

For more patterns see [Python Patterns](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns) (scroll to bottom half of page).

Do you have to deal with multiple digits after "point", ie "two point six seven"?

---

**Edit:** I would classify this as "CatalogStatic with auto-select"

```
class NumberParser:
    def __init__(self, parse_type=None):
        try:
            self.parse = self._parse_types[parse_type]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("invalid parse_type '{}'".format(parse_type))

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_int(str_i):
        """
        Parse `str_i` as an integer
        """
        return 1

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_float(str_f):
        """
        Parse `str_f` as a float
        """
        return 1.

    @staticmethod
    def _parse_auto(str_a):
        """
        Parse `str_a` as int if possible, else as float
        """
        if "point" in str_a:
            return NumberParser._parse_float(str_a)
        else:
            return NumberParser._parse_int(str_a)

    # needs .__func__ on each to work around
    #   static method's need for a calling class
    _parse_types = {
        int:     _parse_int.__func__,
        "int":   _parse_int.__func__,
        float:   _parse_float.__func__,
        "float": _parse_float.__func__,
        None:    _parse_auto.__func__
    }
```

Dispatching can be tested as

```
import unittest

class TestNumberParser(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fp_type_i(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser(float).parse("eight"), 1.)

    def test_fp_type_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser(float).parse("eight point one"), 1.)

    def test_fp_str_i(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser("float").parse("eight"), 1.)

    def test_fp_str_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser("float").parse("eight point one"), 1.)

    def test_ip_type_i(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser(int).parse("eight"), 1)

    def test_ip_type_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser(int).parse("eight point one"), 1)

    def test_ip_str_i(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser("int").parse("eight"), 1)

    def test_ip_str_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser("int").parse("eight point one"), 1)

    def test_ap_i(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser().parse("eight"), 1)

    def test_ap_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(NumberParser().parse("eight point one"), 1.)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: this is the first time I've seen catalog and strategy patterns I guess I still gots a ways to go O>O where can I learn more? the link python patterns don't works :C

Comment: Yes i do have to deal with multiple digits.

Comment: @HughBothwell the Python Patterns link is broken can you fix it. :)

Comment: @MichalFrystacky: fixed now (sorry).

Comment: @HughBothwell Thank you for your contribution! I've already finished my code. You helped me ALOT.